# Looking to scrape a website daily and set up alerts

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I need to run a script that scrapes the following site daily (when the script is run it scrapes the calendar for that day) (the equivalent of clicking on the "daily" button)

http://www.fxempire.com/economic-calendar/

I want to extract all the days data/events for that particular day, and filter for the relevant currencies (if appropriate) and to then create some kind of alert or pop up 10 mins before each of those events are to take place.

I am using the below code so far to scrape the webpage, and then view/print the variable "html" but cannot find the calendar information that I require.

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  



class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()  

url = 'http://www.fxempire.com/economic-calendar/'  
r = Render(url)  
html = r.frame.toHtml()
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Apologies, have now updated the original posting to include the code that I am attempting to use

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best way to scrape data from web pages is to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Here is a quick script that'll get the data you want.

```
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Get a file-like object using urllib2.urlopen
url = 'http://ecal.forexpros.com/e_cal.php?duration=daily'
html = urlopen(url)

# BS accepts a lot of different data types, so you don't have to do e.g.
# urlopen(url).read(). It accepts file-like objects, so we'll just send in html
# as a parameter.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Loop over all <tr> elements with class 'ec_bg1_tr' or 'ec_bg2_tr'
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': re.compile('ec_bg[12]_tr')}):
    # Find the event, currency and actual price by looking up <td> elements
    # with class names.
    event = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_event'}).text
    currency = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_currency'}).text
    actual = tr.find('td', {'class': 'ec_td_actual'}).text

    # The returned strings which are returned are unicode, so to print them,
    # we need to use a unicode string.
    print u'{:3}\t{:6}\t{}'.format(currency, actual, event)
```

To give you some hints of how to solve a problem like this in the future, I've written down the steps I used when solving your problem. Hope it helps.

1. I opened the webpage in Chrome, right-clicked and selected `Inspect Element`.
2. Found the `iframe` with the info in by looking in the elements tab, and opened that url.
3. Inspected this page as well, and figured out that all elements with the data were `<tr>`  elements, and had the class `ec_bg1_tr` or `ec_bg2_tr`.
4. I knew from earlier encounters with BS that it can e.g find all `tr` elements with class `ec_bg1_tr` by using `soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'ec_bg1_tr'})`. My initial though was to first loop over these elements, and then loop over the `ec_bg2_tr` elements.
5. Then I thought that maybe BS was smart enough to accept regexps as input, so I checked their [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression), and it seemed like that shouldn't be a problem.
6. Following the recipe from the docs, I then tried to use the simple regexp 'ec_bg_[12]_tr'.
7. Ca-ching!

Comment: this is really nice solution, i am using it right now for my fundamental analysis, i have other tools like ystockquote python library that i used with some of my code to to some technical analysis on my stock! this is nice and customizable to the max @ Steinar Lima.thank you!